# Java Mail - Attachment missing in received email

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, websphere-liberty

I am using Java Mail API to send mail with pdf as attachment.
See my code below

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        }
);   
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));

System.out.println(toUserEmails);
for(int i = 0 ; i < toUserEmails.length() ; i++){
    String email = toUserEmails.optString(i);            
    message.addRecipients(
           Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(email));
}


for(int i = 0 ; i < ccUserEmails.length() ; i++){
    String email = ccUserEmails.optString(i);
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC,new 
        InternetAddress(email));
}

message.setSubject(subject);   
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setText(body);
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();


 if(!attachment.equals("") && attachment != null){
        System.out.println("attachment base64 is " + attachment);                
        byte[] attach = Base64.decodeBase64(new 
                 String(attachment).getBytes("UTF-8"));

        JSONObject mimeTypes = new JSONObject().put("pdf", 
                              "application/pdf");

        System.out.println(attachmentName);
        String ext = attachmentName.split("\\.")[1];
        DataSource source = new 
                   ByteArrayDataSource(attach,mimeTypes.getString(ext));                
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachmentName);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}
message.setContent(multipart);

Transport.send(message);
```

And it works fine in my local machine which is window 8.
But for some reason when I deploy this code on a server which is on ubuntu, mail is sent without any body, not even text. and an invalid file named "noname" is getting attached.

I have tried restarting server, changing jar file version and changed the code a little bit but nothing works.

I couldn't find anything on stackoverflow.
I am deploying war file on IBM Websphere Application server Liberty.
Can anyone help me?

**Debug output that attaches pdf successfully**

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.0
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.0
asdfsd.pdf
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP r13sm21216626pfl.157 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465

EHLO Yash-PC
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.239.146.50]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: STARTTLS requested but already using SSL
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<stre****@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK r13sm21216626pfl.157 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<yashpatel****@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK r13sm21216626pfl.157 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   yashpatel****@gmail.com
DATA
354  Go ahead r13sm21216626pfl.157 - gsmtp
From: stre*****@gmail.com
To: yashpatel****@gmail.com
Message-ID: <604468520.10.1512892148895.JavaMail.admin@smtp.gmail.com>
Subject: Important Notice
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
boundary="----=_Part_9_1517326996.1512892148882"
------=_Part_9_1517326996.1512892148882
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
This is a notice
------=_Part_9_1517326996.1512892148882
Content-Type: application/pdf; name=asdfsd.pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=asdfsd.pdf
<REALLY LONG BASE 64>
------=_Part_9_1517326996.1512892148882--
.
250 2.0.0 OK 1512892145 r13sm21216626pfl.157 - gsmtp
QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection r13sm21216626pfl.157 - gsmtp
Send
```

**Debug output that fails to attach pdf or body**

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.6.0
O DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
O DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
O DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
O DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
O DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
O ["yashpatel*****@gmail.com"]
O O asdfsd.pdf
O DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
O DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
O DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=root, password=<null>
O DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
O DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
O 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP y2sm5395957otg.51 - gsmtp
O DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465
O EHLO mfppreprod.streebo.com
O 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [198.176.30.250]
O 250-SIZE 35882577
O 250-8BITMIME
O 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
O 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
O 250-PIPELINING
O 250-CHUNKING
O 250 SMTPUTF8
O DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
O DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
O DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
O DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
O DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
O DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
O DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
O DEBUG SMTP: STARTTLS requested but already using SSL
O DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=stre******@gmail.com, password=<non-null>
O DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 
O DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
O DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
O DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
O DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
O MAIL FROM:<stre******@gmail.com>
O 250 2.1.0 OK y2sm5395957otg.51 - gsmtp
O RCPT TO:<yashpatel*****@gmail.com>
O 250 2.1.5 OK y2sm5395957otg.51 - gsmtp
O DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
O DEBUG SMTP:   yashpatel*****@gmail.com
O DATA
O 354  Go ahead y2sm5395957otg.51 - gsmtp
O Date: Sun, 10 Dec 2017 13:07:59 +0530 (IST)
O From: stre******@gmail.com
O To: yashpatel*****@gmail.com
O Message-ID: <1399918662.3.1512891479245@smtp.gmail.com>
O Subject: Important Notice
O MIME-Version: 1.0
O Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
O   boundary="----=_Part_2_376671468.1512891479133"
O .
O 250 2.0.0 OK 1512891481 y2sm5395957otg.51 - gsmtp
O DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server
O QUIT
O 221 2.0.0 closing connection y2sm5395957otg.51 - gsmtp
O Send
```

Comment: Fix any of these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), then post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Comment: Thanks @BillShannon, but I made none of these mistakes.
And I have posted both debug outputs, you can see first one has Content-Disposition and second one doesn't, I really don' t know why.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: @BillShannon No.

Comment: Are you sure?  You've put a try/catch around your code and you get nothing?  It looks like it starts to write out the content of the message and then something goes wrong and the connection is closed.

Comment: @BillShannon I have put try/catch around my code butI am not getting any exception.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas.  Try changing Transport.send to `message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt"));` and then see if msg.txt contains the entire message.  If it does not, you're going to need to step through the JavaMail code to see where it's failing without throwing an exception.  Also try changing your attachment code to something simpler to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @BillShannon not only attachment, whenever I use multipart, even text body doesn't show up. But when I use setContent() to set body, it works. So multipart is causing the problem. Do you think it is encoding problem?

Comment: No, I don’t think it’s an encoding problem.  Did you try what I suggested?  Also, what JDK are you using?  What else is in your class path?

Comment: I am also facing the exact same issue, please help